# SwiftUI NavigationLink: how to call a function before showing destination view

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I would like to call a function, **after** clicking on an item, and **before** displaying the destination view.

The code below doesn't seem to work: `myFunction` is called, but the destination view is not shown.

It looks like the `onTapGesture` overwrites the `NavigationLink` destination.

```
NavigationView {
    List(restaurants) { restaurant in
        NavigationLink(destination: RestaurantView(restaurant: restaurant)) {
            RestaurantRow(restaurant: restaurant)
        }.onTapGesture { myModel.myFunction(restaurant) }
    }
}
```

How can I have both, when clicking on a list item?

- function is called
- destination view is shown

Comment: Can you call the function in `onAppear` in your `RestaurantView`?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58898046/12299030?

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks! eventually, it looks like the best practice is to call `myFunction` onAppear of the RestaurantView. If you write an answer, I will set it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `NavigationLink` into a `Button`, like:

```
Button(action: {
    //Call here
    myModel.myFunction(restaurant)
}, label: {
    NavigationLink(destination: RestaurantView(restaurant: restaurant)) {
            RestaurantRow(restaurant: restaurant)
    }
})
```

**EDIT** pasted test code, try directly

```
 struct TestNavigationView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail").onAppear() {
                    test()
                }) {
                    Text("Click")
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func test() {
        print("Hell0")
    }
}
```

another approach: (might not work if `List` there)

```
struct TestNavigationView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail")) {
                    Text("Click")
                }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                    test()
                })

            }
        }

    }

    func test() {
        print("Hell0")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. The function gets called, but the destination view is not shown.

Comment: @DanieleB I just tried it works, could you just replace your `RestaurantView` and `RestaurantRow` with `Text` only and remove the `onTapGesture` try again?

Comment: I tried that too, but it doesn't work. `myFunction` gets fired, but the destination isn't displayed